# Unable to import pandas on Vscode editor

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio

I am not able to import pandas in VS code editor even though it is already installed.

Attaching the screenshot.[image]

Please help me understand the problem in simpler terms as I am new to Python.

Comment: save it (`crtl+s`) and run it again. If an error occurs post that stacktrack

Comment: hey ch3ster, tried doing that. Getting this error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'